# Can we create a gui for apache web server using php?

Tags: php, user-interface, apache2, webserver

For our university course work we were asked to create a GUI for manage(Editing httpd.conf, creating .htaccsess files, creating certificates etc..) the Apache web server. And it must be web based. So we are planning to use PHP. I just want to know is this a can do (entirely with php) or cant do (without using any other native language support)? Thanks...!

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel? There's plenty of sysadmin-type guis for all kinds of apps, including Apache, e.g. cpanel.

Comment: @MarcB Actually this is for our University Course work. So we cant use them.

Comment: Are you asking whether your university course has assignments that are impossible to pass?

Comment: @Juhana No. I am asking can we do it entirely using PHP without using any other native languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plenty of web-based admin tools already out there. For example, [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) springs to mind.

Of course, if you decide to roll your own, PHP has plenty of [filesystem support](http://php.net/manual/en/book.filesystem.php) and [exec-type features](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) that should allow you to manage any kind of system configuration you like.

Comment: I heard that webmin is out dated and not recommend to use with Ubuntu servers. Is it true?